# In Clojure, how to destructure all the keys of a map?

Tags: clojure

In clojure, it is possible to destructure some keys of a map like this:

```
(let [{:keys [cpp js]} {:cpp 88 :js 90}] 
   (println js); 90
   (println cpp); 88
 )
```

Is there a way to destructure **all** the keys of a map?

Maybe something like:

```
(let [{:all-the-keys} {:cpp 88 :js 90}] 
   (println js); 90
   (println cpp); 88
 )
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Not really, and it wouldn't be a good idea. Imagine:

```
(let [{:all-the-keys} m]
  (foo bar))
```

Are foo and bar globals? Locals? Keys you should extract from m? What should this code do if m *sometimes* contains a foo key, and foo is also a global function? Sometimes you call the global, and sometimes you call the function stored in m?

Ignoring the technical problems (which could be overcome), it is really a disaster for readability and predictability. Just be explicit about what keys you want to pull out; if you frequently want to pull out the same ten keys, you can write a simple macro like `(with-person p body)` that simplifies that common case for you.

Answer (score 11):

This question is pretty old so you've probably forgotten about it, but it came up on google when I was trying to do the same thing, so if I post my solution it might help someone else out.

```
(defmacro let-map [vars & forms]
  `(eval (list 'let (->> ~vars keys
                         (map (fn [sym#] [(-> sym# name symbol) (~vars sym#)]))
                         (apply concat) vec)
               '~(conj forms 'do))))
```

This basically transforms the map `{:cpp 88 :js 90}` into the binding form `[cpp 88 js 90]` then constructs a `let` binding, along with performing some eval-jitsu to make sure that this happens at run time.

```
(def test-map {:cpp 88 :js 90})
(let-map test-map
  (println js)
  (println cpp))
;=> 90
;=> 88
```

Comment: Oh, cmon, this is the only answer actually answering a question in the title. Thanks.

Comment: This is an extremely clever macro. Let's all take a moment to recognize its ingenuity, and then promise ourselves never to write anything like it in production code.

Comment: It may not look like best practice, but I would even argue there are valid use-cases for this construct.

Comment: It does  not really work. `(def test-map {:cpp (Object.)})` blows up `Can't embed object in code`.

Answer (score 7):

You could write a macro to do this (effectively creating a mini-DSL), but I don't think it is a very good idea for the following reasons:

- In order to create the right compile-time literals js and cpp, you would need to destructure the map at compile time. This would be quite limiting in terms of what you could do with it (you would have to specify the keys in advance, and it couldn't use in higher order functions, for example)
- Macros are generally a bad idea when a simpler method would do the job (see below)

I'd recommend just using a simple [doseq](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/doseq) in your case to loop over the map:

```
(let [my-map {:cpp 88 :js 90}]
  (doseq [[k v] my-map]
    (println v)))
```

Note that:

- You can use destructuring as above to extract both the key `k` and value `v` from each map entry
- I used [doseq](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/doseq) rather than [for](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/for) because it is non-lazy and it seems in this  example that you are using the loop only for the [println](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/println) side effects.
- If instead you want a lazy sequence of values (88 90) then [for](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/for) would be appropriate.